# Logstash with helm in Kubernetes : grok filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, logstash-grok, kubernetes-helm

I installed a filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana stack in Kubernetes with helm charts :

```
helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator
helm install --name elastic --namespace monitoring incubator/elasticsearch --set client.replicas=1,master.replicas=2,data.replicas=1

helm install --name logstash --namespace monitoring incubator/logstash -f logstash_values.yaml

helm install --name filebeat stable/filebeat -f filebeat_values.yaml

helm install stable/kibana --name kibana --namespace monitoring
```

The logs are indexed in ES, but the "message" contains the whole string, not the defined fields. My grok filter doesn't seem to work in logstash conf.

The is no documentation on https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/logstash about how to set the patterns.

Here is what I tried :

my log's format :

```
10-09-2018 11:57:55.906 [Debug] [LOG] serviceName - Technical - my specific message - correlationId - userId - data - operation - error - stackTrace escaped on one line
```

logstash_values.yaml (from https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/logstash/values.yaml) :

```
elasticsearch:
  host: elasticsearch-client.default.svc.cluster.local
  port: 9200

patterns:
   main: |-
     (?<time>(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)\.(?:[0-9]){3})} [(?<logLevel>.*)] [(?<code>.*)] (?<caller>.*) - (?<logMessageType>.*) - (?<message>.*) - (?<correlationId>.*) - (?<userId>.*) - (?<data>.*) - (?<operation>.*) - (?<error>.*) - (?<stackTrace>.*)

inputs:
  main: |-
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

filters:

outputs:
  main: |-
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      }
    }
```

This becomes a Kubernetes configMap "logstash-patterns" :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  main: (?<time>(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)\.(?:[0-9]){3}) [(?<code>.*)] [(?<logLevel>.*)] (?<service>.*) - (?<logMessageType>.*) - (?<message>.*) - (?<correlationId>.*) - (?<userId>.*) - (?<data>.*) - (?<operation>.*) - (?<error>.*) - (?<stackTrace>.*)
```

I don't see any error logs in logstash pod.

Do you have any idea how to configure patterns in logstash in Kubernetes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was mistaking "pattern" and "filter".

In the Helm chart, "pattern" is for specifying our custom grok patterns (https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns) :

> MY_CUSTOM_ALL_CHARS .*

My grok filter should be in the filter section :

```
patterns:
  # nothing here for me 

filters:
  main: |-
    filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "\{%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\} \[%{DATA:logLevel}\] \[%{DATA:code}\] %{DATA:caller} &\$ %{DATA:logMessageType} &\$ %{DATA:message} &\$ %{DATA:correlationId} &\$ %{DATA:userId} &\$ %{DATA:data} &\$ %{DATA:operation} &\$ %{DATA:error} &\$ (?<stackTrace>.*)" }
        overwrite => [ "message" ]
      }
      date {
        match => ["time", "ISO8601"]
        target => "time"
      }
    }
```